# SML Uncaught exception Empty homework1

Tags: smlnj

> Question: Write a *function number_before_reaching_sum* that takes an int called sum, which you can assume
> is positive, and an int list, which you can assume contains all positive numbers, and returns an int.
> You should return an int n such that the first n elements of the list add to less than sum, but the first
> n + 1 elements of the list add to sum or more. Assume the entire list sums to more than the passed in
> value; it is okay for an exception to occur if this is not the case.

I am quit new on SML, and coudn't find out anything wrong with this simple exprssion. The error message Please help me to debug the code below

```html
fun number_before_reaching_sum (sum:int, xl: int list) =
    if hd xl = sum
    then 0
    else
    (hd xl) + number_before_reaching_sum(sum, (tl xl))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a couple of steps of your solution on a short list:

```
    number_before_reaching_sum (6, [2,3,4])
--> if 2 = 6
    then 0
    else 2 + number_before_reaching_sum(6, [3,4])
--> 2 + if 3 = 6
        then 0
        else 3 + number_before_reaching_sum(6, [4])
--> ...
```

and you see pretty clearly that this is wrong - the elements of the list should not be added up, and you can't keep looking for the same sum in every tail.

> You should return an int n such that the first n elements of the list add to less than sum, but the first n + 1 elements of the list add to sum or more.

This means that the result is 0 if the head is *greater than or equal* to the sum,

```
if hd xl >= sum
then 0
```

Otherwise, the index is *one* more, not `hd xl` more, than the index in the tail.
Also the "tail sum" you're looking for isn't the original sum, but the sum without `hd xl`.

```
else 1 + number_before_reaching_sum(sum - hd xl, tl xl)
```